# A coin is flipped 6 times in a row.

Tags: probability

A coin is flipped $6$ times in a row.

a. What is the probability that it never lands heads up?

b. What is the probability that it lands heads up exactly $3$ times?

c. What is the probability that it lands heads up at most $3$ times?

**My attempt**

b) $p=\frac{1}{2}$

$q=p=\frac{1}{2}$

so, I got ${6\choose 3}(\frac{1}{2})^3(\frac{1}{2})^3$

c) $p=\frac{1}{2}$

$q=p=\frac{1}{2}$

so, I got $ {6\choose 3}(\frac{1}{2})^3(\frac{1}{2})^3\times{6\choose 2}(\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^4\times{6\choose 1}(\frac{1}{2})^1(\frac{1}{2})^5$

Comment: This is all related to binomial distribution. Part a) for example you want six times tales, so $0.5^6$.

Comment: In part (c), the coin lands heads up $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$ times.  Probabilities of mutually exclusive events add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) is $$\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^6=\frac{1}{64}$$

b) is $$ \binom{6}{3}\cdot\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^6=\frac{5}{16}$$
c) is $$ \bigg[\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{0}\bigg]\cdot\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^6=\frac{42}{64}$$

where $$\binom{n}{r}=nCr=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

a) $C(6,0)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^0\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^6$

b) correct

c) you missed the term $C(6,0)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^0\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^6$ and you should add the probabilities of mutually exclusive events, not multiply.